# Gradle share properties in multi-project

Tags: gradle

I'm quite new to Gradle, trying to make multi-project. In root project declares all common libs (also their versions as properties) and apply plugins.

For example, `root` and child `common` projects.
In `root`'s `settings.gradle` type:

```
rootProject.name = 'root'
include 'common'
```

In `root`'s `build.gradle` type:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

subprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'kotlin'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And now I'd like to use another library only in specific child project.  Do this in `common`'s `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

It's work fine when running gradle commands from `root`'s folder, but failed with message `Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler` when running from `common`'s folder.

What I'm doing wrong? Or is there any way around? And what are best practices for sharing libs and properties in multi-project?

For me, it looks like `common` know nothing about it's "parent" project, all relations defined in root's settings.

Comment: What's the failed message in common's folder ?

Comment: @Eugene my answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101642/10426557

Comment: It says `Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler`, sorry didn't mention it at first time

Comment: @JonathanJohx didn't see how spring boot or boot jar related to the abstract problem with properties in multi-projects

Comment: @Eugene then did you do this enable jar and disable bootJar? In your build.gradle of common subproject

Comment: @JonathanJohx no, I didn't

Comment: Try my answer, and let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: I mean, I get why you asking about Spring, but the question is more about properties from a parent project or any advice for a better structure for sharing properties and dependencies between project

Comment: You didn't say where should I add this try both `build.gradle`, but it didn't help to build `common` project, fails with 'unknown property/

Comment: I didn't tell you about Spring, are you sure about it? The issue that you have is because common folder is being recognize like an application then you should follow my answer in order to can fix it.. Just within build.gradle add those lines.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101642/10426557

Comment: Those lines didn't help. `bootJar` related to Spring Boot, isn't it, why disable something from 'boot' if it is not even in dependencies?
To be clear, the project builds fine from root’s folder and failed to build from common’s folder.

Comment: Which Gradle version are you using?

Comment: @Eugene oh right, I saw you updated your question, so gradle is not recognizing your property klotin_version because root folder is defined the property, ok I'll update my answer.

Comment: @thokuest Gradle 4.10.2

Comment: @thokuest https://bitbucket.org/evlgorbachev/gradle-properties/ gradle build doesn't work from a common folder but works from a project root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why Gradle cannot resolve the property is because the project in folder `common` is named `commons`. This is caused by a spelling mistake in `common`'s `settings.gradle`. This is fortunately easy to fix (`common/settings.gradle`) :

```
rootProject.name = 'common'
```

Alternatively, just delete the `common/settings.gradle`, it's fully optional in this case.

Consider reading the official Gradle documentation for [authoring multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and the guide [create multi-project builds](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) for more information and best practices around multi-project builds.

Comment: Nah, it's just my inattentiveness. The child project had the same name as included `common`. And again, it work's when calling `gradle build` from root project folder and fails when calling `gradle build` from common project folder.
For me it looks like common doesn't know that it has "parent" project, all relations defined in `root`'s settings

Comment: @Eugene Please review your question and make sure it's accurate. Maybe it's possible to provide the project via Github?

Comment: For some reason mention doesn't work in this thread. https://bitbucket.org/evlgorbachev/gradle-properties/

Comment: Removing `common/settings.gradle` helps. 
But why it doesn't work before? Did Gradle look for `settings.gradle` in current folder first and then goes up in tree?

Comment: @Eugene Yes, simple as that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!